# How can I retrieve all local notifications I scheduled with flutter_local_notifications plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification

Assuming I created multiple local notifications on Android (for instance in a for-loop) with the `flutter_local_notifications` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) using the code below:

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
0, // should always vary
'scheduled title',
'scheduled body',
tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(minutes: 10)),
const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'your channel description')),
androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
    UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
```

Is there any way I can easily retrieve a list of the scheduled notifications or do I need to take care of myself persisting these scheduled notifications?

Reading the documentation I could not find a way provided by the library itself.